# Drawing a 12 Point Burst ❋ using CSS

Tags: css

In this [page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) following CSS to draw 12 point burst, how can I put some text inside it (in current form it does not show text inside text, I test z-index without success)?

How can I draw a 12 burst border in it most clean manner?

```
#burst-12 {
    background: red;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#burst-12:before, #burst-12:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: red;
}
#burst-12:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}
#burst-12:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to nest another element inside the burst container:

```
<div id="burst-12"><span>I am the text</span></div>
```

Then you can style it the way you want:

```
#burst-12 span {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}
```

You'll find a very basic example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gz4w9/).

Comment: Thanks, How can I draw a 12 burst border?

Comment: @PHPst a bit more tricky, I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gz4w9/1/. What you need is another burst which is nested in the first one. The outer burst is the border the inner the content container.