# Divide a circle into 24 segments using css

Tags: css, geometry, segment

I have created a circle using css. Now I want to divide it into 24 segments. How can I perform this using css. Help me.
Here's my code for how I created circle:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
.circle{

            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: blue
            }
```

[image: Final Result looks like this:]

Comment: see this link   


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495687/drawing-a-12-point-burst-using-css

Comment: you are definitely choosing the wrong tool for the job, whatever you're trying to do

Comment: @ Andy: Can you please tell me the mistakes I have made?

Comment: You should be using something like svg or canvas to do geometric drawing

Comment: @Andy: Now I'm using svg.. I think it's a better solution. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform it more easily by using Scalable Vector Graphics.

code to draw circle:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

You may draw different lines, so that you can divide the circle into segments.

Code for line:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```